# Unable to start the Activity(Contains inter-fragment communication)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am basically new to Android Development. Learning from various YouTube Channels and ufcourse following the official API guide.

I am currently learning about fragments and found a video for the similar need. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5swuGl3bDg&index=12&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo) is the link to it.

What I have basically done is make two fragments, One fragment(**`FragmentA`**) contains a simple `ListView` and when I click on the List item , the corresponding content should be shown in the fragment below namely : **`FragmentB`**.

I have followed all the steps as shown in the tutuorial, but still at the runtime I get the following error :

```
08-04 15:19:47.038  22144-22144/com.example.abhishek.fragmentmodularui E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abhishek.fragmentmodularui/com.example.abhishek.fragmentmodularui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2107)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2132)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1920)
                at com.example.abhishek.fragmentmodularui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2132)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.abhishek.fragments.FragmentA: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
                at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4828)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1920)
                at com.example.abhishek.fragmentmodularui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2132)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.abhishek.fragments.FragmentA
                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
                at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
                at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4828)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1920)
                at com.example.abhishek.fragmentmodularui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2132)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my rest of the code :

1) MainActivity.java : http://pastebin.com/6r2a15AN

2)FragmentA.java : http://pastebin.com/UMDMKWVi

3)FragmentB.java : http://pastebin.com/i5q1pHdq

4)Communicator.java : http://pastebin.com/fw0HbQa7

5)strings.xml : http://pastebin.com/Q0Qb7D6n

6)activity_main.xml : http://pastebin.com/8mw2cEHs

7)fragment_a.xml : http://pastebin.com/mq7RmSLe

8)fragment_b.xml : http://pastebin.com/Px90HWLN

9)AndroidManifest.xml : http://pastebin.com/bX71e80s

What is the problem here ? Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Comment: There is a mistake in activity_main.xml, on this line in fragment2: `android:layout_below="@+id/fragment"`, you mistakenly use the `+` sign when referring to an existing id

Comment: @milez : But this is a new project ... Shouldn't I be using `+` ?  Because I have not mentioned `id` parameter anywhere else

Comment: You use `+` when you create _new_ ids. In that line you _refer_ to an existing id. So no plus used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Fragment`s and `Activity` seem to be in package `com.example.abhishek.fragmentmodularui`. In your `activity_main.xml`, both the fragment names point to files that do not exist:

```
android:name="com.example.abhishek.fragments.FragmentA"
```

This should probably be

```
   android:name="com.example.abhishek.fragmentmodularui.FragmentA"
```

and respectively

```
   android:name="com.example.abhishek.fragmentmodularui.FragmentB"
```

Additionally your implementation of the `respond()` method is wrong. Shown below for reference.

```
public void respond(int i) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB(); //This is WRONG
    fragmentB.changeData(i);
}
```

Here you should not create a new Fragment like you do, because they are created when `Activity` starts. What now happens a new fragment is created but is not initialized so you see errors. You should get the existing fragment from `FragmentManager`. The correct way is

```
public void respond(int i) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    fragmentB.changeData(i);
}
```

but you will have to figure out the parameters `bundle` and `key` on your own.

Comment: exactly I did that change and my app run... but now it displays the list as expected . but when i click on the list I get the following error : http://pastebin.com/ZD5UL3qR

Comment: I added an explanation for that

Comment: I understand sir .. So how do I write that code ? How do I get an instance of `FragmentB`

Comment: you were correct about the initialization of the fragment.. But it should be done like this : `FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);`... But thanks for pointing out the problem and I would appreciate if you make the necessary edits as I have pointed out in your answer as I am marking your answer as "Accepted".. Thanks again

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Nice job figuring it out and thanks :) I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy there are some things you are doing wrong way it will be better if you study some details from android developer site 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html
there is download link to download sample project study that 
you have done this which is wrong

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        communicator = (Communicator)getActivity();
        listView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.titles,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }
```

You should do like this

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);
listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.titles,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: I do not understand.. I have written the same exact code

Comment: check your fragmentA java file

Comment: I learned that I should not be using the code in onCreateView as in the LifeCycle the Activity's onCreateView should complete first and then only Fragments' view will be generated... I guess I have some other problem.. I just noticed I am getting an error in `activity_main.xml`

Comment: There is no onCreateView() in activity its in fragment only buddy